# Why are there different technique to measure distance between two vector?

Tags: data-science-model

While learning for ML, came across different ways to means the distance between vector Like L1 norms, L2 norms, Lp norms and Cosine. Beside the formula of each of these methods, how are these different for our objective find how are each vector differ or distance between two vector.